# Make a textbox display my company name dynamically

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

For example, if you have a barcode system scanner, and you have a textbox that shows the total amount after items were scanned with barcode, after you print the bill, I want the textbox of total amount of money text to display my company name like a screen saver but only in the total textbox. I want the company name text to move continuously to the left in the textbox that shows the total during the time that there are no items to scan or sale.

It's like a screen saver, but it should show the company name or whatever.

I have no idea how to do this. Do I have to use a loop like

```
for step 0 to n loop>>txtTotal.text="Company Advertisement"
```

? But in the next step I want this text to move left for about 10 pixels and then again and again and disappear and start over during there are no items to scan.

Code:

```
Dim i As Double = CDbl(Me.txtTest.Location.X) 
While i >= 1 
    Me.txtTest.Location = New Point(i, Me.txtTest.Location.Y) 
    i -= 0.0001 
    If Me.txtTest.Location = New Point(1, 0) Then 
        Me.txtTest.Location = New Point(675, 0) 
        i = Me.txtTest.Location.X 
    End If 
End While
```

Comment: it moves the textbox to left but i think my computer is going to explode due to infinit loop. Any better idea? Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms?

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't scroll text in a textbox by a number of pixels in VBA (*if* you're using VBA) *or* VB .NET.  All you can do is remove the first character and add it to the end of the value string.

```
Dim i As Double = CDbl(Me.txtTest.Location.X)
While i >= 1
    Me.txtTest.Location = New Point(i, Me.txtTest.Location.Y)
    i -= 0.0001
    If Me.txtTest.Location = New Point(1, 0) Then
        Me.txtTest.Location = New Point(675, 0)
        i = Me.txtTest.Location.X
    End If
End While
```

You would need to place the code to do this in the Form_Timer event (VBA) or attached to a timer object (VB .NET), and set the timer interval to an appropriate non-zero value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an animation in Xaml to define as you want size, speed, ... of the moves of your text.
Search for animation or storyboard on google or msdn. 
The animation would start when billing ended, and stop when billing starts.
One part of the animation could be a fade-in/out of opacity when text appears/disappear, then you could do a back and forth movement, simpler than an infinite scroll.

And if you want your text to be 'inside' the textbox, most simple seems to have both the textbox and the advertising text within the same grid (advertising text being defined after, of course).

Comment: This appears to be Windows Forms, though…